# Basic flowchart maker with text input (no graphical interface)

Tags: flowchart

I want to 'type' the flowchart data in a standard editor, specifying connections etc.

Then, when finished, the program generates a flowchart.

Comment: What OS, what price? Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you saw Dia.

Anyway here is a list of free programs for flowchart design, maybe it's among these.
https://opensource.com/article/18/8/flowchart-diagramming-linux

Answer (score 0):

I think the best possible free tool available is [Draw.io](https://about.draw.io/about-us/). It will generate the drawings in a XML format if you like and there is heavy portability embedded to the tool.